# Highlighting two div cells simultaneously

Tags: jquery

I have two div tables with same values, and when I click a cell it is highlighted with the assigned color. The code works on both tables separately. What I need is when a cell is clicked and highlighted, the other cell with the same value is highlighted too. This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/304bynga/). Thank you for your help.

*Note: I need to be able to highlight multiple different values on two tables at the same time.*

Html:

```
<input class="btn_colors" data-color="#9ac99d" type="button" name="green" id="green" value="Green" />

    <div class="table1">
    <div class="column">
    <div>6</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="table1">
    <div class="column">
    <div>6</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.column {
  float: left;
}
.column div {
  border: 0.4px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0.02px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 12.9px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table1 { width: 30px; float:left;  margin:1px; margin-left:0px;margin-top:50px;}
.content { overflow: hidden; }
```

Jquery:

```
// variables
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_colors');
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.column > div');
var current_color = document.getElementById('green').getAttribute('data-color');

// listener for button clicks
for (let i = 0, c = buttons.length; i < c; i++)
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', set_color, {
    passive: false
  });

// listener for number cells
for (let i = 0, c = numbers.length; i < c; i++)
  numbers[i].addEventListener('click', set_bg, {
    passive: false
  });

// functions
function set_color(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  current_color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
}

function set_bg(event) {
    if(this.classList.contains('clicked'))
  {
    this.classList.remove('clicked');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    return ;
  }

  this.style.backgroundColor = current_color;
  this.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the required div in all div elements.

```
function set_bg(event) {
    // Selecting all div elements and the finding the required div using Array.find()
    var anotherDiv = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).find(div => {
      return div != this && div.innerText == this.innerText; 
      // finds the div which have the same value as the current div.
    });

    if(this.classList.contains('clicked'))
  {
    this.classList.remove('clicked');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    anotherDiv.classList.remove('clicked');
    anotherDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    return ;
  }

  this.style.backgroundColor = current_color;
  this.classList.add('clicked');
  anotherDiv.style.backgroundColor = current_color;
  anotherDiv.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

[Working Example](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/xyEdmX?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try or use this code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".column div").click(function(){

        $(".column div").css('backgroundColor', '#fff'); // you may add this or not :)
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(".column div:contains("+text+")").css('backgroundColor', 
        $(".btn_colors").attr("data-color"));

    })

});
```

Comment: Thanks, Vinia. I needed to highlight multiple cells